# How to print field values horizontally in iReport?

Tags: java, ireport

I want to print my field values horizontally (by default they are getting printed vertically). I placed a field in detail section, now instead of getting them printed:

aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
.
.
.

I want the values to be printed like:
aaa     bbb       ccc        ddd   ...

I am using iReport 4.0.0.

Answer (score 2):

a) **`Crosstab Report`**, video tutorial [1](http://ireport-tutorial.blogspot.com/2008/10/ireport-crosstab-report.html) / [2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gtfFc0ez9xw)
b) or **`Columns`** : Report properties :

- Columns
- Print Order -> Vertical / Horizontal

Comment: Hi .I change the Print Order -->Horizontal but the result is not print Horizontal .
Thanks

Comment: @user700819 The **Print Order** is only supported for multicolumn report. Did you set the **Columns > 1**?